# Views supertable + Views Bluk Operation

Tags: 7, views

I want to use views supertable with views bulk operations but when I choose the format "jQuery Supertable" the bulk views operations doesn't work.
Any body has face the problem,or is any other solution because I need to use the jquery filter to select multiple users from the table of the view.

Comment: Works fine on my installation. Please write this issue to the issue queue of the views supertable module and we can solve it out there.

Comment: can you please indicate me which version of views , vbo and views supertable are you using?